# XDebug installed but not working

Tags: php, xdebug, wampserver

I have just downloaded the latest xdebug for my windows machine running wamp and php 5.3.  After following the install instruction and restarting my services, it appears to be installed according to php info:

xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.1.0

However, if I try to use the following in a script:
xdebug_start_trace('c:\test.txt');

I get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function xdebug_start_trace() i

What is going on?

Thanks,
Jonah

Comment: WampServer has two php.ini files, one for Apache web pages, one for CLI. Make sure you've edited the correct one.

Comment: The installer gives you precise instructions about the location based on your phpinfo.  Mine was "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.ini".  So I don't think that's the problem, especially since phpinfo is now saying it's installed.

Comment: This `php.ini` is for CLI. For webpages there's another at `C:\wamp\www\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin`

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  I can't mark it as an answer because it's just a comment.

Comment: there's the answer for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WampServer has two php.ini files, one for Apache web pages, one for CLI. Make sure you've edited the correct one.

The `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.ini` is for CLI. For webpages there's another at `C:\wamp\www\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin\php.ini`

Comment: Nope... when you get Wampserver with debug and enable from Php settings it sets it in both

Comment: Perhaps that's how it works in November 2012, but it's not the way it did in January 2011. Back then xdebug was not part of Wampserver package.

Comment: Ah... I see... funny it still doesn't work with Eclipse though. I tried but then got a tip to just shift to ZendDebugger and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A few unique things about xdebug: Your php.ini needs to start with `zend_extention=` not `extension=`. And on Linux you need to supply the full path to xdebug.so (same as xdebug.dll) even if it's in the same directory as the rest of your extensions. Windows is probably the same.

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply, but i am already doing both of those things.